# How can I fix this program? (python)

Tags: python

My task is to make a program.

In the code there is variable called num1, num1 has to be digits only and with the length of 5.

The code should print every digit in num1 and their sum.

The problem here is that if num1's length is not 5 it's not working, as well if there is chars in num1 that aren't digits.

It seems like the problem is in the condition.

Please tell me what is not good in my program (I'm still a beginner in python)
EDIT : Thanks for the help! i appreciate it, i got along with it, the new code is the right one. :D

```
max_value = 5

def main():
    global max_value
    #This line requests from you to put an input with 5 digits
    num1 = raw_input("Please enter a number with 5 digits\n")
    bol = check_everything(num1)
    if bol is False:
        while (len(num1) != max_value) or (num1.isdigit() == False):
            num1 = raw_input("Please enter a number with 5 digits and with 
digits only\n")
    num1 = int(num1)
    printer(num1)


def check_everything(num1):
    if (len(num1) == max_value) and (num1.isdigit() == True):
        return True
    else:
        return False


def printer(num1):
    summ = 0
    s1 = ''
    for x in xrange(max_value):
        s1 += str(num1)[x] + ','
    print s1[:-1:]
    while num1 != 0:
        summ += num1 % 10
        num1 /= 10
    print(str(summ))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! In order for us to help you better, can you please update your question so that it shows all relevant code in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), showcasing the code in the question **itself**, rather than simply linking to an image containing it. Being able to copy the code helps us to debug it much faster. For further information, please refer to the help article regarding [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [**tour of the site**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Comment: Which version of Python are you using? You have mixed calls to `print` that I am leery of. Additionally, you are assigning to the variable `sum`; which I would not consider best practice as `sum` is a builtin. Lastly, there are multiple syntax errors throughout the program. Line 6 & 9 need to be commented and line 42 has the incorrect indentation for being in the `if __name__ == '__main__':` block. Please post a minimal, complete and verifiable example for further discussion, as well as the error you think you are geting.

Comment: Does your edited code run? If so, in which version of Python? You still have mixed calls to `print` and line 10 has a newline in the middle of the string literal. Syntax errors found and tested in Python 3.6 64 bit Windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
max_value = 5


#The main function, it only summons the other functions and gets an input for num1.

#If the value entered in the functions is not ok, a loop happens in the main function.
def main():
    global max_value
    #This line requests from you to put an input with 5 digits
    num1 = input("Please enter a number with 5 digits\n")
    bol = check_everything(num1)
    if bol == False:
        while (len(num1) != max_value) or (num1.isdigit() == False):
            num1 = input("Please enter a number with 5 digits and with digits only\n")
    num1 = int(num1)
    printer(num1)


def check_everything(num1):
    if (len(num1) == max_value) and (num1.isdigit() == True):
        return True
    else:
        return False


def printer(num1):
    numsum = 0
    s1 = ''
    for x in range(max_value):
        s1 += str(num1)[x] + ','
    print(s1[:-1:])
    for i in range(len(str(num1))):
      numsum = numsum + int(str(num1)[i:i+1])
    print(str(numsum))


if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

Answer (score 0):

> My task is to make a code. in the code there is variable called num1, num1 has to be digits only and with the length of 5. the code should print every digit in num1 and they're sum. The problem here is that if num1 length is more than 5 or less than 5 it's not working, as well if there is chars in num1 that aren't digits.

This sounds like homework.

Additionally, you code example is a screenshot. Please include the complete example code in a formatted code block in the body of your question.

More detail is also necessary, but I think the following may be a good starting point for you to start thinking about how to refine your question:

```
import re

def print_numbers_and_sum(input_string: str):
    """
    Find all numbers in an input string, print them and their sum
    """

    all_numbers = []

    # Using Regular Expressions (re), define a pattern 
    # that will catch numbers from the input string
    number_pattern = r"[-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]*"
    number_regex = re.compile(number_pattern)

    # Iterate over the matches in our input string
    for number_string in number_regex.findall(input_string):

        # the input string can potentially be empty
        if number_string:

            current_number = float(number_string)
            all_numbers.append(current_number)
            print(current_number)

    # Sum is part of the standard library and will sum values in an iterable
    print(sum(all_numbers))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    input_string = "-206.35 and another number 4005.32"
    print_numbers_and_sum(input_string)
```

Comment: Hey, I fixed it, I'm new here sorry :)

Comment: Hey, i 100% fixed it now, sorry i didn't know how to write the question.

Comment: @RoshaAE Please see my comment on the OP

Answer (score 0):

You can set conditions using a `while loop` that will only accept a `string` that meets the requirements of having a `len of 5` and `is.digit()`

```
num1 = input('Enter a number with a length of 5: ')
while len(num1) != 5 and num1 != num1.isdigit():
        num1 = input('Please enter a number with a length of 5: ')
num1 = int(num1)
```